# How to echo message to a file in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to log down the variable_A value by redirect the echo to variable_A.log as below:

```
echo $variable_A >> variable_A.log
```

But instead of printing the value to my log file, it actually treat "$varaible_A >> variable_A.log" as string and printed on the prompt.

Comment: `% echo $variable_A >> variable_A.log
can't read "variable_A": no such variable
%   `

Comment: I tried in `tclsh` with the variable defined and not defined, In both, I got the desired result. What you see above is when it is used without existence of `variable_A`

Comment: I ran my command from script... Would that be the problem? I have check and ensure that the variable exist...

Answer (score 2):

To append a value to a file, you need to open the file in the right mode and use the two-argument form of `puts` (the one-argument form is defaulting to writing to `stdout`). Let's make a trivial procedure to do it:

```
proc appendToFile {message >> filename} {
    set f [open $filename "a"];   # The “a” is the key part
    puts $f $message
    close $f
}
```

Now we can use that dead easy:

```
appendToFile $variable_a >> variable_A.log
```

The `>>` in this case is *just* syntactic sugar. It has no value at all other than to make what you're doing easier to read. (`>>` is a legal — but quite strange — variable name in Tcl.)

Answer (score 1):

This is less efficient, but easy to grok:

```
exec echo $message >> filename
```

In an **interactive** tclsh session, it will work without the `exec` due to the way the defalt `unknown` procedure is defined.